# Пуш нотификации не приходят на ios девайсы

Tags: ios, cordova, app, уведомления

Делаем апк для android/ios используя cordova.
В приложении есть пуш-нотификации и они работают на android, но не работают для ios, хотя настраивали их используя [этот мануал](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

Собственно, порядок действий был такой:

1. Создали [app](https://developer.apple.com/) PushHotification com.vsale.notification
2. скачали сертификат (тип development) и загрузили в keychain на маке.
3. скачали ключ к серитификату.
4. выполнив несколько команд получили сертификат с ключем в pem формате.

   ```bash
   openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem
   openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in PushChatKey.p12
   cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
   ```
5. проверили сертификат

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
   ```

   ошибок не выдало.
6. Сиблдили апп
7. Используя php код отправили нотификации на APNS

   ```php
   // Open a connection to the APNS server
   $fp = stream_socket_client(
       'tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
       $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

   // Send it to the server
   $result = fwrite($fp, $message, strlen($message));
   ```
8. Получили ответ об удачной отправке

   > ios
   >
   > Connected to APNS
   >
   > Message successfully delivered"

   Но нотификации на девайсы не пришли.

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: если вы пишете на кордове, почему не использовать плагин под нее? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Answer (score 1):

1. Когда создавали сертификат - сначала запрашивали ключ из keychain? 
   Ассистент сертификации > Запросить сертификат на у бюро сертификации?
2. Создали ли вы Provision file? и добавили его в проект и делали сборку под нужным Provosion file?
3. Попробуйте скачать программу [PushMeBaby](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/PushMeBaby).
   В ней можно самому опробовать приходят ли пуши или нет. Вы просто добавляете сертификат и токен девайса. И сам пуш (там пример есть) и если придет, то с сертификатом все нормально.